# Multi-language module in Wordpress or Google sites

Tags: multi-language

Which is an easy software for creating a simple multi-language website? I'd like a button to switch from English to German, for example. I don't want to write code, possibly. Thanks, Carlo

Comment: I guess you need a translation module in wordpress. Not sure if it exists, maybe someone else can explain how to integrate it without programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with the use of Wordpress and plugins you should take a look at WPML plugin at http://wpml.org/

It's working quite well, even for non-programming users.

Answer (score 0):

There are a host of other options for wordpress on http://www.webdesignbooth.com/wordpress-multi-languages-5-plugins-to-built-a-multilingual-website/